# How to create a new column by an if statement in a pipeline builder where I need to use two different columns?

Tags: pipeline, palantir-foundry

I
Appreciate help in my learning process in the Pipeline Builder with screenshots or videos.

I want to create a new column name, “campaign”
If sales is 500$ and region is North then the campaign column result will
Be “Y” else “N”
End

Answer (score 0):

import pandas as pd

## Create a DataFrame

df = pd.DataFrame('your data')

## Define a function to apply the conditions

def create_campaign(row):
if row['sales'] == 500 and row['region'] == 'North':
return 'Y'
else:
return 'N'

## Apply the function to create the 'campaign' column

df['campaign'] = df.apply(create_campaign, axis=1)

## Print the resulting DataFrame

print(df)

Answer (score -1):

In Pipeline Builder you need to apply a transform as described [here in Docs](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/pipeline-builder/transforms-transform-data/index.html/). There is a transform for CASE that accomplishes what you describe in your original post -- having a condition for both a Sales numeric and Region string.

Make sure to select matching all conditions (it sounds like that's your aim) and name the output column as you wish.